# JSON.NET serialization trouble

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

I have a class with property type of Point ( struct in .NET Framework).
I use JsonConvert from Newton.Json to serialize it to JSON.
But result is

```
 "Point" : "100,100"
```

Instead of

```
 "Point" : { X: "100", Y: "100"}
```

When I replace JsonConvert with standard JavascriptSerializer,
all works fine.

But I want to use JsonConverter from JSON.Net, because it's much faster.

Comment: yes, but I want to use JsonConverter from Json.Net, becouse it much faster.

Comment: Do you mean `System.Drawing.Point`, `System.Windows.Point`, or some other type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `Point` has defined its own `TypeConverter` and JSON.NET uses it to do the serialization. I'm not sure whether there is a clean way to turn this behavior off, but you can certainly create your own `JsonConverter` that behaves the way you want:

```
class PointConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var point = (Point)value;

        serializer.Serialize(
            writer, new JObject { { "X", point.X }, { "Y", point.Y } });
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jObject = serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader);

        return new Point((int)jObject["X"], (int)jObject["Y"]);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Point);
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new { Point = new Point(15, 12) },
    new PointConverter())
```