# SignalR is sending my struct wrongly

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

So, after trying to understand whats happens with my messages in a big class... i've found out with a small test that:

```
public struct Test
{
  public int X {get;set};
  public int Y {get;set};

  public Test(int x, int y)
  {
    X = x;
    Y = y;
  }
}

// hub
var sendMe = new Test(12,20);  
Clients.All.Test(sendMe);
```

...and client gets Test = (0,0)!

Looks like a big bug.
Do i need to fill a bugreport?

Comment: Does it work if you have a class instead of struct? And btw. what does it mean "send my struct wrongly"? What exactly happens - can you show the traces because maybe it is not the server that "sends it wrongly" but the client that serializes it incorrectly?

Comment: It works with a class as expected. Does not work with a struct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because JSon.NET (which is used by SignalR client to deserialize payload) does not handle structs by default. You can change your struct to a class.

Comment: You could also write your own [JsonConverter implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22713839/3191303)..,